# Parsing multiple RSS feed with feedparser but it doesn't finish loop

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm trying to get news feed from different RSS sources my code looks like this :

```
entries = []
for i in rss : 
    dictio_headline = feedparser.parse(i)
    entries.extend(dictio_headline["entries"])
    print (i)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(entries)
df = df3[["title","summary","link"]]
```

Where RSS is a list of RSS news feed, my problem is that my code stop running ( it keeps running but it doesn't go to the next URL in my list and can stay like this for hours )
after the 20th or 21st iterations of my loop but i don't get why.
I tried to suppress the RSS link from my loop but it keeps stopping at the 20th or 21st depends. Do you think it's a problem of memory ?